# Why does karma-runner needs a browser for Angular unit test

Tags: angular, browser, karma-runner

I would like to understand why `karma` runner needs a browser to run `Angular` unit test. I would like to emphasize the "WHY".

I have tried to search for the answer, but all I have found is that recomendation to use `phantomjs` or headless chrome, etc, but not an answer for WHY it needs it. I am curious and want to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same reason Java unit test need a JRE: the browser is executing your javascript compiled code

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was lookimg for.So basically the browser provides the runtime env. Cool.

Answer (score 1):

Because Karma was *designed* to execute **source code** against **test code** for a **browser(s)**.

From the official docs > [*How It Works*](https://karma-runner.github.io/4.0/intro/how-it-works.html)

> Karma is essentially a tool which spawns a web server that executes
>   source code against test code for each of the browsers connected.

Actually, there was a question posted in the [karma mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/karma-users), asking [Can tests be run without a browser?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/karma-users/without$20browser%7Csort:date/karma-users/FPKWGMCxNfc/XVsl-2ozgZsJ), whose answer posted by Vojta Jina ([contributor](https://github.com/vojtajina)) states:

> Karma works only with browsers, so use PhantomJS if you want it to be
>   headless. We don't use it as Chrome or Safari are faster than
>   PhantomJS.

Comment: I know that. But it does not say WHY it needs a browser and not something else. Anyway, thanks for your effort. Btw, what is the role of the browser ? Why can't we use a webserver instead ?

Comment: It's like a triage: what does karma run?: source code, how should it be ran?: according to the tests specifications, where?: in a browser (the platform).